# Typing for the Navigation API

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, navigation-api

Where can I find some typings for the drafted [Navigation API](https://wicg.github.io/navigation-api/) implemented in Chrome ?

Comment: I mean... wouldn't be too hard to write them based off of [Section 1](https://wicg.github.io/navigation-api/#global)... Practically wrote itself ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install the types separately:

```bash
npm install -D @types/dom-navigation
```

It was [added](https://github.com/WICG/navigation-api/commit/498d3e4dad08132a84de7de2bfcf7922a12fd161) to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/dom-navigation/index.d.ts) by the [Web Incubator Community Group repo](https://github.com/WICG/navigation-api)

Comment: That's a good start, I'll ask DefinitelyTypes if they are interested in a package !

Comment: I made an [extended version](https://gist.github.com/JeanMeche/108ce377105b07146bc1887950f04e46)  which includes `NavigationEvent` & `document.createDocumentTransition` if anyone is interested

Comment: The link is broken.